# Can I no longer pass ViewData to _Layout.cshtml in MVC Core 1.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I'm trying to pass a URL for a background image to my `_Layout.cshtml`,

```
public HomeController()
{
    this.ViewData["BackgroundImage"] = "1920w/Stipula_fountain_pen.jpg";
}
```

and

```
<body style="background-image: url(@(string.Format("assets/images/{0}", ViewData["BackgroundImage"])))">
    ...
</body>
```

but `ViewData` is always empty inside `_Layout.cshtml`. Is that working as intended? I'd rather not go down the `BaseViewModel/BaseController` route as that feels like overkill.

EDIT: It seems as if `ViewData` set in the constructor isn't actually used, because once an action is executing the collection is empty. If I set `ViewData` inside the action then that data is passed on to `_Layout.cshtml` - feels like a bug to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an action filter to set `ViewData` for all controller actions:

```
public class SetBackgroundUrlAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        if (result != null)
        {
            result.ViewData["BackgroundImage"] = "1920w/Stipula_fountain_pen.jpg";
        }
    }
}

[SetBackgroundUrl]
public HomeController()
{

}
```

Or just override `OnActionExecuted` method of the controller:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(context);
        var result = context.Result as ViewResult;
        if (result != null)
        {
            result.ViewData["BackgroundImage"] = "1920w/Stipula_fountain_pen.jpg";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [adem caglin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5426333/adem-caglin)'s answer I went with this filter attribute, which can take an arbitrary URL:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class|AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class SetBackgroundUrlAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Url))
        {
            var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;

            if (result != null)
                result.ViewData["BackgroundImage"] = this.Url;
        }
    }

    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

and is used like so:

```
[SetBackgroundUrl(Url = "1920w/Stipula_fountain_pen.jpg")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```